# Gridview search on ASP.NET

Tags: sql, asp.net, search, gridview

I'm trying to make a simple ASP.NET application which draws data from a mdb file with insert, delete, edit, search options.

After i added Gridview and a sqldatasource on my page i selected Datasource from Gridview tasks. And i checked Enable editing, enable deleting from there. For insert i added a textbox and a button. For button i wrote this.

```
OleDbConnection con= new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("App_Data\\veritabani.mdb"));
con.Open();
string name= txtname.Text;
string lname= txtlname.Text;
string idno= txtidno.Text;
string job= jobbox.SelectedItem.ToString();
string age= txtage.Text;
OleDbCommand add= new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Tablo1(name, lname, idno, job, age) values ('" + name + "','" + lname+ "','" + idno + "','" + job+ "','" + age+ "')", con);
int check= add.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (check> 0)
    lblInfo.Text = "<font color=green>Successfull</font>";
else
    lblInfo.Text = "<font color=red>Unsuccessfull.</font>";
con.Close();
con.Dispose();
```

Insert works fine. But i cannot create a search button. What do write on my search button? I wrote this but i didnt work.

```
 OleDbConnection con= new OleDbConnection();
        OleDbCommand komut = new OleDbCommand();
        komut.Connection = con;
        komut.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Tablo1 WHERE name LIKE '%" + namesearch.Text + "%'";
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(komut);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

I don't want to use AJAX, Devexpress etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ASPX**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Text1" runat="server" ToolTip="Search"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" onclick="Button1_Click" ToolTip="Search" />

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LocalSqlServer %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ Tablo1]"
                FilterExpression="name LIKE '%{0}%'">
                <FilterParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter Name="name" ControlID="Text1" PropertyName="Text" />
                </FilterParameters>
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**CS**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
            GridView1.DataBind();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FilterExpression="name  +' '+ lname LIKE '%{0}%'"
```

Comment: It works but if lastname textbox is empty it does not work. I want it to search with entered values. (both or just one)

Comment: Set `CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false"` on the SqlDataSource1
and in ControlParameter `ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"`